# ContentPlaceHolder not working

Tags: asp.net, umbraco

I need your help:
Asp ContentPlaceHolder is not working.
"blao balo bla balll" is not shown.
in Html code:

```
<!-- Insert default "slide" markup here -->
```

This is my Code - HomePage.master:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/umbraco/masterpages/default.master" AutoEventWireup="true" %>

<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolderDefault" runat="server">

<asp:ContentPlaceHolder Id="slide" runat="server">
    <!-- Insert default "slide" markup here -->
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

</asp:Content>
```

slide.master:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/masterpages/HomePage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" %>

<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="slide" runat="server">
     blao balo bla balll
</asp:Content>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Just to be sure: your content does use `slide` as it's template, and not `HomePage` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `slide` template uses the `HomePage` template as master page and replaces the content of a ContentPlaceHolder defined in the `HomePage` template, you should make sure to use the `slide` template whenever you want to display non default slide markup.

When using the `HomePage` template, as expected the default markup as defined in the `HomePage` template gets displayed.